# Flutter Integration Test: Mock Application Class Values

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I want to mock my App state values in integration_test package in Flutter. Suppose I have a class that returns my particular sensor is on/off or permission is granted or not. They have a function like `isOn()`. In case of integration testing I want that returns always true. How can I mock that values which loads while integration Test?

N.B.: Shared Preferences values are modifiable using the following method `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({})`. but don't know how can I modify Custom class values.